# Find Esbern in the Ratway Warrens but he’s at Sky Haven Temple

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During the quest “A Cornered Rat“, I am supposed to find Esbern in the Ratway Warrens, but the quest marker shows him in Sky Haven Temple. I have gone back a few saves, but the problem still persists. I have exited my game and gone back in and it still occurs. I’m not sure what exactly I’m supposed to do here. Any advice?

Comment: Do you have any mods loaded? He's not suppose to be out of his cell until the quest finished.

Comment: Have you tried fast travelling away and back again?